# Modules and multiple inheritance in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, multiple-inheritance

I learn modules behave as a multiple inheritance in ruby on rails. I saw an example which I understand but what if two modules have same methods then which one call?

```
module A
  def a1
  end

  def a2
  end
end

module B
  def a1
  end

  def b2
  end
end

class Sample
  include A
  include B

  def s1
  end
end

samp=Sample.new
samp.a1
samp.a1
```

Comment: Next time please spend some seconds to properly format your code so that it's more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby does not have multiple inheritance. Ruby has something similar called [mixins](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html#S2) which can be implemented using Modules.

Mixins are not multiple inheritance, but instead mostly eliminate the need for it.

To answer your question, when you include two modules in a class and both of them has the method with same name (in your case, method `a`), in that case, `a` method from the 2nd (the last one) Module will be called.

```
module A
  def a1
    puts "I am defined in A"
  end

  def a2
  end
end

module B
  def a1
    puts "I am defined in B"
  end

  def b2
  end
end

class Sample
  include A
  include B

  def s1
  end
end

samp = Sample.new
puts samp.a1
# I am defined in B
```

#### Why and How?

> When a module M is included in a class C, an anonymous proxy class
>   ⟦M′⟧ (called an include class) is created such that  its method table
>   pointer points to M's method table. (Same for the constant table and
>   module variables.)  ⟦M′⟧'s superclass is set to C's superclass and C's
>   superclass is set to ⟦M′⟧.

Also, if M includes other modules, the process is applied recursively.

```
puts Sample.ancestors.inspect
# [Sample, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

It becomes more clear when you inspect the `ancestors` of the `Sample` class. See the order here. When `a` method is called, Ruby looks for the method definition first in `Sample` class itself, but doesn't find it. Then, it looks for the `a` method in `B` and it finds it and calls it.

Hope it is clear to you now.

Comment: Its clear...but if I want to call A a1 in that situation.Is it possible?

Comment: You mean, you want to call the `a1` method of the `A` module directly? like `A.a1` ?

Comment: To be able to call `A.a1` you have to define the `a1` method in `A` module like class method: `def self.a1 . . . end` Then, you can call `A.a1` directly.

Comment: `def self.a 
puts 'I am in A module' 
end` inside `A` module. Then you can call: `A.a1`

Answer (score 0):

The last wins. In your example (that you could have tried on your own running it on the console with a print statement) the `a1` method that will be called is the one defined in `B`.

Comment: Yes but any logic in it?

Comment: That's a design decision that was taken when Ruby introduced that feature and the price to pay when dealing with ambiguous names. If you want to access `A.a1` you can always call `super` from inside the other method.

Comment: How can I call A.a1? syntax of that?